# Incorrect Japanese font rendering inside NSControl object

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, localization

I'm building a UI application in macOS with dynamic localization (meaning that it's possible to switch language while the application is running).

I've noticed that if the initial language is configured to Japanese, and I switch to English on-the-fly, the text on the controls is rendered ok. 
However, on the opposite case, when the initial language is English and I switch to Japanese on-the-fly, the Japanese symbols on the text field come out a little bit enlarged. (see below drawings to emphasize the difference - the left snippet is the original rendering while the right one represents the enlarged version)

[image: The original text]
[image: The enlarged text]

For any particular control, the language is changed by simply assigning the localized string (taken with help of `NSLocalizedString` function) to the `stringValue` property of the control.

These results appeared on all versions I've tested (both 10.13 and 10.12).

Perhaps anybody encountered similar results? how should I resolve them ?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the rendering problem is resolved if the Language is properly installed on your machine under `Language and Regions -> Preferred Languages`